# ehcache client failover on terracotta

Tags: ehcache, failover, terracotta

I'm trying to use OSS Ehcache with terracotta cluster, but failed to implement failover from the ehcache client-side.

I find this configuration as stated in the documentation [here](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.2/clustered-cache.html)

```
<ehcache:service>
<terracotta:cluster>
  <terracotta:connection url="terracotta://localhost:9510/clustered"/>
  <terracotta:server-side-config auto-create="true">
    <terracotta:default-resource from="default-resource"/>
  </terracotta:server-side-config>
</terracotta:cluster>
</ehcache:service>
```

but this connection accepts only one URL. I want to have HA with failover, if I have two terracotta servers in a cluster.
something like ActiveMQ failover url:

```
failover:(server1:port,server2:port)
```

My question: Is that possible in opensource ehcache, or I'll need to have the enterprise version, and if it possible, how to configure that.

**Update**

I tried 
`<terracotta:connection url="terracotta://host1:9510,host2:9610/clustered1"/>`
as mentioned by [Louis Jacomet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42419848/1900758) but, that didn't parse correctly, giving:

```
org.ehcache.xml.exceptions.XmlConfigurationException: Error parsing XML configuration at file:/F:/Work/WORKSPACES/java7_ws/CachingTest/target/classes/ehcache.xml
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:131)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider$ConfigSupplier.getConfiguration(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:324)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/F:/Work/WORKSPACES/java7_ws/CachingTest/target/classes/ehcache.xml; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 91; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'terracotta://host1:9510,host2:9610/clustered1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '\w+://([^\]\[/?#@]+@)?[^:?#/]+(:[1-9][0-9]{0,4})?(/[^\?#]*)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?' for type 'connectionUrl'.
```

If I try `<terracotta:connection url="terracotta://host1:9510/clustered1,host2:9610/clustered1"/>` which compiles well, but if *host1* goes down, the client gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.ehcache.StateTransitionException: org.terracotta.connection.ConnectionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.ehcache.core.StatusTransitioner$Transition.failed(StatusTransitioner.java:235)
    at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:588)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.createCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:148)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:128)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:79)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:183)
    at dev.ams.poc.CacheApp.main(CacheApp.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.terracotta.connection.ConnectionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.ehcache.clustered.client.internal.service.DefaultClusteringService.initClusterConnection(DefaultClusteringService.java:189)
    at org.ehcache.clustered.client.internal.service.DefaultClusteringService.start(DefaultClusteringService.java:140)
    at org.ehcache.core.internal.service.ServiceLocator.startAllServices(ServiceLocator.java:118)
    at org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager.init(EhcacheManager.java:560)
    ... 5 more
```

Ehcache version: Ehcache-clustered-3.2

Answer (score 1):

This feature is part of the open source offering, no issue there.

You need to list the multiple `server:port` in there, as in:

```
<ehcache:service>
  <terracotta:cluster>
    <terracotta:connection url="terracotta://localhost:9510,otherhost:9510/clustered"/>
    <terracotta:server-side-config auto-create="true">
      <terracotta:default-resource from="default-resource"/>
    </terracotta:server-side-config>
  </terracotta:cluster>
</ehcache:service>
```

Listing all servers is the recommended way to go, otherwise you need a very precise understanding of the failover logic.

Comment: Thank you, I tried like you said, it's compiled, but failover hasn't succeed when the first server went down, and connectionException fired:
    <terracotta:connection url="terracotta://localhost:9610/clustered1,localhost:9510/clustered0"/>

Comment: your URL does not match the example I gave. You repeat the servers before the path as the path element needs to remain the same. So `terracotta://localhost:9610/clustered1,localhost:9510/c‌​lustered0` needs to become `terracotta://localhost:9610,localhost:9510/c‌​lustered`

Comment: I used      terracotta://host1:9510,host2:9510/clustered, but that failed at xml parsing, giving: XmlConfigurationException,
I use IPs instead of host names.

Comment: Please add that information to the question including the stack trace. It should work as announced.